# How can I pass keyword arguments as parameters to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

Say I have a function defined thus:

```
def inner_func(spam, eggs):
    # code
```

I then want to call a function like this:

```
outer_func(spam=45, eggs="blah")
```

Inside `outer_func` I want to be able to call `inner_func` with exactly the same parameters that were passed into `outer_func`.

This can be achieved by writing `outer_func` like this:

```
def outer_func(spam, eggs):
    inner_func(spam, eggs)
```

However, I'd like to be able to change the arguments `inner_func` takes, and change the parameters I pass to `outer_func` accordingly, but without having to change anything in `outer_func` each time.

Is there a (easy) way to do this?  Python 3 please.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do.  It seems like you want `func_one` to call `func_two`, and that sometimes you want the same parameters and sometimes you want different ones.  Which is vague.  Can you provide an example of the functionality you want?

Comment: When you say "without changing the definition of `outer_func`", do you mean without changing it every time you change `inner_func`, or do you mean the definition should still say `def outer_func(spam, eggs):` exactly the way it does now when you're done?

Comment: @user2357112 I mean the first option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the `*` and `**` notations:

```
def outer_func(*args, **kwargs):
    inner_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can do `outer_func(1, 2, 3, a='x', b='y')`, and `outer_func` will call `inner_func(1, 2, 3, a='x', b='y')`.

If you only want to allow keyword arguments, drop the `*args`.

---

In a function definition, a parameter marked with `*` receives a tuple of all positional arguments that didn't correspond to other declared parameters, and an argument marked with `**` receives a dict of all keyword arguments that didn't correspond to other declared parameters.

In a function call, prefixing a sequence (or other iterable) argument with `*` unpacks it into separate positional arguments, and prefixing a mapping argument with `**` unpacks it into separate keyword arguments.

Comment: ..."without changing the definition of `outer_func`"

Comment: @wim: I'm pretty sure that's intended to mean "without changing the definition of `outer_func` every time I change `inner_func`", but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, that's an interpretation I hadn't considered.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew about using the * as an argument, but I didn't know you could use it to unpack a tuple or dict when passing function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I'm getting your drift but you may find `functools.wraps` interesting:

```
@functools.wraps(inner_func)
def outer_func(*args, **kwds):
    return inner_func(*args, **kwds)

inspect.signature(outer_func)
# <Signature (spam, eggs)>
```

Explanation: The "star arguments" collect all the not explicitly specified postional (*args) and keyword (**kwds) arguments that were passed. They can also be used to pass these parameters on; or to manipulate them: `args` is a tuple and `kwds` is a dict.

Since for example parameter `spam` will end up either in `args` or `kwds` depending on how it was passed, manually parsing star args can be tedious. Here the `inspect.Signature` class and in particular its `.bind` and `.bind_partial` methods are useful.

`functools.wraps` is a convenience function/decorator that tweaks many special attributes of the decorated function to make it look like the wrapped function. In particular it copies the name, the signature, the doc string and whatever may be in the wrapped functions `__dict__`.

This makes wrapper functions much more user friendly.

Comment: You should explain what `functools.wraps` actually does, because it isn't actually responsible for any part of the job of forwarding arguments here. It only updates metadata like the function's `__name__`.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair enough, will do.