# Pass function argument to another function with mutation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code following

1. `func1` takes bunch of arguments (exact no is not know in advance)
2. Adds one more argument (lets say `extra`) based on some logic Pass
3. all these arguments to the next function `func2`.

Following is what I tried

```py
def func2(*arg):
    #Some logic
    pass

def func1(*arg):
    arg["extra"] = 1
    func2(**arg)

func1(var1=1, var2=2)
```

However, this is not successful and giving `TypeError:unexpected keyword argument`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change `func2(**arg)` to `func2(*arg)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass keyword arguments as parameters to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724242/how-can-i-pass-keyword-arguments-as-parameters-to-a-function)

Comment: You need to change the function definitions to accept keyword arguments: `def func2(**arg)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` does iterable unpacking and `**` does dictionary unpacking (which you have by suppling argument names), so you want to use `**kwargs` instead of `*args`

```py
def func2(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    pass

def func1(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    func2(**kwargs, extra=1)

func1(var1=1, var2=2)
```

Output:

```py
{'var1': 1, 'var2': 2}
{'var1': 1, 'var2': 2, 'extra': 1}
```